# after connecting wifi with WifiWizard2 cross mark showing on devices wifi and no internet on ionic 5 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I connected wifi with WifiWizard2.connect from ionic app and but no internet is working .

async connectToNetworkWifiWizard2(ssid: string, password: string, WPA2) {
console.log('connectToNetworkWifiWizard2', { ssid, password, WPA2 });

```
return new Promise(async (resolve) => {    
  const formatWPAConfig = await WifiWizard2.formatWPAConfig(
    ssid,
    password,
    true
  );
  console.log('formatWPAConfig', formatWPAConfig);

  const WifiWizard2Add = await WifiWizard2.add(formatWPAConfig);
  console.log('WifiWizard2Add', WifiWizard2Add);

  const result = await WifiWizard2.connect(
    ssid,
    true,
    password,
    WPA2,
    true
  );
  console.log('result indise platform', result);
  const getConnectionInfo = await this.hotspot.getConnectionInfo();
  const canConnectToInternet = await WifiWizard2.canConnectToInternet();
  console.log('canConnectToInternet', canConnectToInternet);

  this.wifiSsid = getConnectionInfo;
  resolve({ result, connectedWifi: this.wifiSsid, canConnectToInternet });
});
```

}

successful internet connectivity from app and internet should work outside app